# Scala: Extend base class that contains 'apply' method

Tags: scala

I have a base class in the 'common' module that looks like this:

```
class BaseClass(args: Seq[String] = Seq()) extends Serializable {
  private val argMap: Map[String, String] = 

 // <More code here...>

object BaseClass {
 def apply(args: Seq[String] = Seq()): BaseClass = new BaseClass(args)
}
```

Now I want to extend this BaseClass in my 'module' so I am trying this...

```
class MyNewClass(args: Seq[String] = Seq()) extends com.xyz.BaseClass {
   // Add additional code here
}
object MyNewClass extends com.xyz.BaseClass {
  def apply(args: Seq[String] = Seq()): MyNewClass = new com.xyz.MyNewClass(args)
}
```

My understanding is, when I instantiate MyNewClass it will automatically instantiate & call the 'apply' method of the base class but that's not happening. What is a proper way to extend the BaseClass in a way that all its variables & methods can be accessed via the Child class?

Comment: You probbaly want to call the cosntructor: `class MyNewClass(args: Seq[String] = Seq()) extends com.xyz.BaseClass(args)`

Comment: It was that simple. Thanks @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My understanding is, when I instantiate MyNewClass it will automatically instantiate & call the 'apply' method of the base class...

Your understanding isn't quite on.

`extends com.xyz.BaseClass` means that this class inherits from the base `class`, not the singleton `object`.

And `new com.xyz.MyNewClass(args)` creates a new instance of the specified class, bypassing the `apply()` method in any companion object.

> What is a proper way to extend the BaseClass in a way that all its variables & methods can be accessed via the Child class?

The current code does exactly that. `MyNewClass`, and its companion object, inherits all members from `BaseClass`. Nothing is inherited from the `BaseClass` companion object because you can't extend an `object`, and you don't inherit the access permissions from `BasseClass` so while a `BaseClass` instance can access private members of the `BaseClass` companion object, a `MyNewClass` instance cannot.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Makes sense! In the calling class I added new MyNewClass(args) as suggested by  @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez  & it's working. Your explanation helped to learn a bit more so Thank you.